# How can I perform a union with two single-field Matlab structs

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I currently have two single-field Matlab structs that list image names. I would like to combine them into a single struct with no duplicates - i.e.

```
a(1).img = 'aa.jpg'
a(2).img = 'bb.jpg'

b(1).img = 'bb.jpg'
b(2).img = 'cc.jpg'
```

I would like for ab to have value(s):

```
ab(1) = 'aa.jpg'
ab(2) = 'bb.jpg'
ab(3) = 'cc.jpg'
```

Is there a non=brute force way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the values from each of the structs using a comma-separated list followed by `unique` to get the unique values. Then, passing this to the `struct` function will create an array of `structs` containing the values.

```
S = struct('img', unique({a.img, b.img}, 'stable'))
```

If you don't actually need a struct out and just want a cell array of the unique values, you can eliminate the final call to `struct`.

```
unique({a.img, b.img}, 'stable')
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Yea that should work as well. Probably a bit cleaner

Comment: I've actually just used: `unique({a(:).img, b(:).img})`

Comment: @user1245262 In this context, the `(:)` is unnecessary

Comment: @Suever - Thanks. What does the 'stable' argument do?

Comment: @user1245262 By default `unique` will sort the values. `'stable'` ensures that they remain in the order that they first appeared.